# Wrapping binary IO

Tags: python, stream, lazy-evaluation

I originally asked this on IRC, but it's probably the worst sort of question to actually get answered there:

> How can I wrap a binary stream/buffer without just reading the entire buffer into memory, doing the manipulation on that, and creating a new buffer from the result?

Specifically I'm talking about the original stream being an in-memory `io.BytesIO` object or the result of `open` with the `b` (binary) flag set.

My current application for this is to resize an image in chunks just before each is sent over HTTP (which is clearly beyond the scope of this question), but I'm also generally interested in how to deal with changing the behaviour of a buffer without wrecking its interface.

Comment: Are you asking about *lazy* operations, or about rewinding a stream afterwards (so that, for an open file, calling `read` afterwards will still read from the beginning)?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of this is basically to avoid pulling giant objects into memory and then operating on the whole thing (so, laziness). I'm fine with the sort of behaviour generators have where each chunk can only be read once, that is, rewinding or non-sequential chunk access  aren't important. (By "chunk" I just mean some part of the whole, not necessarily of a fixed size or comprising something independently useful.)

Comment: Oh, another thing: if the original stream is buffered and has some fixed chunk size that differs from the chunk size the wrapper knows how to process, it's fine to pull in enough chunks to do the processing even if a part-chunk from the original stream will remain and need to be carried over to the next iteration of processing.

Comment: I'll try to formalize my question a bit, hang on.

Answer (score 0):

A BufferedStream will wrap a raw IO stream, and can then be read as needed by your resize function:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams

Comment: If you start with a buffered stream, can that be wrapped in a raw IO stream (presumably this would just read in enough whole chunks from the buffered stream to provide the requested view of the raw stream and handle carrying over excess, assuming sequential access to the raw stream, which is all I care about) so your method can be used? Did that make sense?

Comment: It's the other way around...the raw IO stream is wrapped by the buffered stream.  Otherwise I think your explanation is correct..the buffered stream will manage reading the correct amount of data from the underlying raw stream as necessary.

Comment: What I mean is that if I'm writing something that doesn't get to choose whether it gets passed a raw stream and it gets passed a buffered stream, to use your method it sounds like I first need to convert that buffered stream to a raw stream so it can then be wrapped with a buffered stream with the chunk size set to something the resize function knows how to deal with.

Comment: I think you need to add the code for your client class so we can see what you're trying to do.